# Jquery JSON appended <li> can't get length

Tags: jquery, json, append

i already looked up a lot of sites and threads but couldn't find an answer for my issue.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Pizza Margharita": {
        "price1": "4,50 &euro;"
    },
    "Pizza Caprese ": {
        "price1": "4,00 &euro;"
    }    
}
```

My jquery-function like this:

```
  $(function() {
    $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(name, price) {
        $('section#food01').find('ul').append('&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="#order"&gt;&lt;h3&gt;'+name+'&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;span&gt;'+price.price1+'&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;');
      });

    });
    var food01size = $('#food01 ul li a').length;
    $('#food01 li a').live('click',function(){
      alert(food01size);

    });
  });
```

I need to get the .length of the li or a elements. The value for foodsize01 is always "0". That's because the data is loaded asynchron.

Anybody ideas what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the issue is because you are loading the data asynchronously. The count is firing before any elements have been appended. You'll need to move that code into your success callback function:

```
  $(function() {
    $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(name, price) {
        $('section#food01').find('ul').append('&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="#order"&gt;&lt;h3&gt;'+name+'&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;span&gt;'+price.price1+'&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;');
      });
      var food01size = $('#food01 ul li a').length;
      $('#food01 li a').live('click',function(){
        alert(food01size);
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare food01size as 0, then set it inside the complete function of the getJSON:

```
  $(function() {
    var food01size = 0; //original declaration
    $.getJSON('data/food01.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(name, price) {
        $('section#food01').find('ul').append('&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="#order"&gt;&lt;h3&gt;'+name+'&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;span&gt;'+price.price1+'&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;');
      });
      food01size = $('#food01 ul li a').length;//set new value
    });
    $('#food01 li a').live('click',function(){
      alert(food01size);
    });
  });
```